# Installing wifi on debian

Tags: debian, wifi, software-installation, drivers, thinkpad

I'm currently trying to get wifi running on my debian machine which I've installed on my Lenovo Thinkpad P51.

So I've already installed Network manager and the wireless tools but unfortunately, this is where I'm stuck. I read that I need to install a driver but I'm not sure which one I need to install. How do I find out ?

Comment: You need to provide the output of `lspci` and `lsusb` in your question. In particular the line(s) that mention your WiFi and/or Network devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I read that I need to install a driver but I'm not sure which one I
>   need to install. How do I find out ?

Please read the **[official Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi).**

If you follow the instructions there you *should* be able to get wireless working. My guess is that you will need to add a `non-free` component to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

`deb http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib`

and then install the required firmware (quite possibly `iwlwifi`).

But... do [read the documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi) first. If you are still stuck after that, get back with as much **[detail](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/PCI)** you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

maulinglawns's answer is generally correct. Here's the short cut I took to get an specific answer for you.

1. Find the brand and model number of your wifi chipset. I did this by
   web-searching for "Lenovo p51 wifi" and came up with "Intel 8265".
2. Per maulinglawn's answer, add the `non-free` debian repository to your
   `/etc/apt/sources.list`. The simplest, mindless way to do this is `echo "deb http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`.
3. Perform `apt-get update` in order to load the information for the new repository.
4. Look for a debian package for that firmware. `apt-cache search
   "firmware-" |grep Intel`. This displayed a promising result,
   `firmware-iwlwifi`.
5. Double-check. `apt-cache show firmware-iwlwifi |less`. Search for
   8265 using the search feature of the `less` pager by pressing forward
   slash "/" followed by 8265.

So it seems that installing package `firmware-iwlwifi` from the
standard debian repository should do the trick. Let us know how it went!

Comment: Umm... The `firmware-iwlwifi` is **not** in the standard Debian repository: https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi

Comment: By gads, you're right! So sorry. I'll edit my post now.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. Sure, not the cleanest format but it helped me. Maybe adding some information about `lspci` and `lsusb` would be helpful but especially 4. and 5. of this answer were helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Or to add to @user1404316, after you have checked your hardware (web search does suggest Intel 8265) then linux support is also offered at [intel.com](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)